# NSPredicate predicateWithFormat with object that changes over time

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

I have this working code, but now i need to be able to change the NSPredicate, based on the object used in the predicateWithFormat as follows:

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription 
                               entityForName:@"Item" inManagedObjectContext:_context];

[fetchRequest setPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self.atrObj == %@", _currentUser.atrObj.objectID]];

[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

NSSortDescriptor *sortContent = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date" ascending:NO];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sortContent]];
[fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:10];
NSFetchedResultsController *theFetchedResultsController = 
[[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest 
                                    managedObjectContext:_context sectionNameKeyPath:nil 
                                               cacheName:nil];

self.fetchedResultsController = theFetchedResultsController;
self.fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
```

I need the fetchedResultsControlelr to use the new _currentUser object when i change the _currentUser object from the app delegate which has this tableviewcontroller a property.

```
[self.tableViewcontroller setCurrentUser:user];
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the predicate anytime but be sure to re-fetch via `performFetch`. Also from Apple docs:

> **Important**: Important If you are using a cache, you must call deleteCacheWithName: before changing any of the fetch request, its
>   predicate, or its sort descriptors. You must not reuse the same
>   fetched results controller for multiple queries unless you set the
>   cacheName to nil.

Also, from the Apple docs of `NSFetchedResultsController`:

> Modifying the Fetch Request You cannot simply change the fetch request
>   to modify the results. If you want to change the fetch request, you
>   must:
>
> - If you are using a cache, delete it (using deleteCacheWithName:).
>     Typically you should not use a cache if you are changing the fetch
>     request.
> - Change the fetch request.
> - Invoke performFetch:.

Comment: Thank you!!! i did not know you could change the predicate at any time, nice thing to know!

Answer (score 1):

Whenever the value of `currentUser` changes, do this (perhaps inside the setter):

```
NSError *error = nil;
self.fetchedResultsController.fetchRequest.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"atrObj == %@", self.currentUser.atrObj];
if(![self.fetchedResultsController performFetch:&error]) {
    // Handle errors
}
```

Comment: Thank you!!! i did not know you could change the predicate at any time, nice thing to know!